# PHP date() function gives the wrong time

Tags: php, centos

```
 date('d-m-y h:i:s A')
```

The above code displays the correct date but the wrong time. It isn't off by hours either; even the minutes are off. I have set the default time zone in PHP using the function as well as in php.ini, set the date and time on my server, and restarted it. Any ideas why it still won't work? I'm running CentOS with Apache and PHP. All are the latest versions.

[Update] Looks like it's a problem with my system clock. It resets itself to some random time whenever I manually update it. I've tried disabling ntpd but it still does this, not sure why. I'm not sure if should close this question or open a new one.

[Another Update] I set the timezone in Linux and even went into WHM > Server Configuration > Server Time and set it to update the date and time. It said it successfully updated it and displays the correct date and time, but as soon as I refresh it or check it on the server it's back to this other date and time. I can't tell at this point if it is reverting back instantly or not being set at all without throwing errors.

Comment: run `date` from the command line to check the actual date and time of your server

Comment: php gets its timestamp values from the underlying OS and hardware. If php's date is completely wrong, then so's the underlying server's. PHP does NOT maintain its own independent clock.

Comment: Have a look at ntpd if it's not installed already: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-ntp-to-synchronize-server-clock/

Comment: I already tried ntpd after manually setting the server's date and time, and this did not work either :( I've also run date from the command line and it is correct on the server.

Comment: Are you writing a standalone script, or are you writing code for a larger application?

Comment: Just a quick Google: http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&order=DESC&topic_id=38432&forum=55 Good luck!

Comment: It is for a stand alone application. All it does it record the date and time a form is submitted.

Comment: By any chance, is there anything in your root crontab that could be changing the system date, such as a call to ntpdate, or the like?

Comment: No there is not. I tried installing ntpd but that didn't solve the problem so I disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `date_default_timezone_set` it's work true. I've had the same problem.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
```

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I found out some VPS hosts don't let you change the time on your own VM, so I had to take out a support ticket and have them fix it. If anyone else is having similar issues then I'd suggest asking your host first.